# RxJava pattern for returning cold results, doing more work, then returning hot results

Tags: android, design-patterns, rx-java

I'm learning RxJava so please be gentle. I've watched the tutorials, done the reading, searched SO, however, I'm still having some problems transforming my `AsyncTaskLoader`. For some reason, I can't find a pattern of operators to achieve my task (although I think it's a common one). What I'm trying to do is the following: return an Observable my fragment could subscribe to. The observable should do the following on subscribe:

1) Fetch data from the local database by doing 2 queries, running some logic and returning results;
2) Fetching data from API;
3) Synchronising the new API data with the database;
4) Repeating step one and returning results;

So far I've transformed my db calls and my API calls to return observables. I'm trying to understand how I can emit the cold results and continue with the chain. I could probably keep the two operations separately, and use the same subscriber to subscribe to both? But I'm not sure how that would work if my new loader-replacement class returns an observable... Also I don't really need to process the results from the second observable - I just need for the first one to replay when the second one finished.

So far I have the following:

```
 public Observable<StuffFetchResult> getColdStuff() {
    return Observable.zip(mDataSource.listStuff(), mDataSource.listOtherStuff(),
            (stuff, moreStuff) -> {
                List<Stuff> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
                // do some merging stuff
                return new StuffFetchResult(mergedList);
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
 }
```

Assume I also have `getHotStuff()` that will do the API call and the synchronisation with the database, if that's the right approach, and return the same `Observable`. However, I'm stuck on the next step - how can I restart the first observable to replay once `hotStuff` has completed, without adding another subscriber?

**EDIT:**

I've made some progress and I think all I need now is to join it all up. I have my two methods:

1) `getColdStuff()` is pretty much as described above
2) `getHotStuff()` will do call to the API, synchronise with the database, and return an Observable. The idea was to call `getColdStuff()` again after `getHotStuff()` has finished in order to refresh the UI, so actual result returned from `getHotStuff()` can be ignored. All it needs to do is to trigger `getColdStuff()` once done.

I've tried the suggestion in the answer to and created the following:

```
BehaviorRelay<Observable<StuffFetchResult>> callSequence = BehaviorRelay.create();
Observable<StuffFetchResult> valueSequence = Observable.switchOnNextDelayError(callSequence.toSerialized());
valueSequence.subscribe(new Subscriber<StuffFetchResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {}

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {}

    @Override
    public void onNext(StuffFetchResult result) {
        // UI stuff
    }
});
callSequence.call(loader.getColdStuff());
```

I can subscribe to `valueSequence` here and use   `callSequence.call(loader.getColdStuff());`, which will run the first method and produce results in `onNext()` of my subscription, which I can use for my UI. However, I'm not sure how to run `getHotStuff()` in parallel and also do a different action on it when it returns. Also `getHotStuff()` returns a different type of `Observable` so I can't really use the same `callSequence`?

**EDIT 2**

Using two subscribers, I can achieve the required behaviour I think. Not really sure if that's the right way to go about it though.

```
 loader.getHotStuff()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe( new Subscriber<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object stuffWeDontCareAbout) {
            callSequence.call(loader.getColdStuff());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your scenario correctly, you may want something like that -

```
BehaviorSubject<Observable<T> callSequence = BehaviorSubject.create();
Observable<T> valueSequence = Observable.swithOnNextDelayError(callSequence.toSerialized());
```

your subscriber will be listening to the *valueSequence*, and whenever you need to "restart", you will call this -

```
callSequence.onNext(call.cache()); // *call* is Observable<T>
```

(i leave the .subscribeOn/.observeOn configuration to you)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you please elaborate a little bit as I'm not sure how to use your suggestion? Also I've noticed that my methods `getHotStuff` and `getColdStuff` return different types of observables - as originally `getHotStuff` would fetch from API, persist, then call `getColdStuff` to retrieve from storage. So presumably they can't both be in the `callSequence`? The behaviour I'm looking for is: `getCold -> resultsToUI -> getHot -> persist -> getCold - resultsToUI`

Comment: for side effects, such as persisting to storage, .doOnNext() is the proper place. to use alternative data source if the first one is empty, .switchIfEmpty(alternate) is the typical solution. so the whole chain would be something like storage.switchIfEmpty(apiCall.doOnNext(persist())); different type of observable is hardly an issue, you can use .map()

Comment: Thanks again. I'm still trying to put this together.. It's not that I need to use an alternative data source, it's actually the opposite - I need to use both, first showing data from stale source, then updating when I have fresh data. But I'm not sure how to connect it all in one single flow. I'm gonna update my question with the latest code in case you might have another minute to have a look. Thanks

Comment: i suppose you want to start the update from API ASAP, i.e. in parallel. so, i would first subscribe UI to "valueSequence", then call "callSequence.onNext(hotStuff.doOnNext(/*persist*/).flatMap(/*to coldStuff*/).cache());". this way you will get UI updated before and after API call

Comment: I think that nearly works. I get the hot stuff doing its thing, I get coldStuff running after hotStuff, nearly magical. The only problem I have now is that the initial coldStuff is not run, and Ideally I'd like it to run in parallel with the hotStuff. However if I try to add two calls to `callSequence`, only the last one get through.